# How to get latest bot response in rasa Chatbot?

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core, rasa-x

How to get latest bot response with Rasa Chatbot? 
For getting user input we use : tracker.latest_message['text'] 
So, what is syntax for getting latest bot response ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `tracker.events` list to fetch the latest bot event.

```
bot_event = next(e for e in reversed(tracker.events) if e["event"] == "bot")
```

This will go through the reversed list of events (making it from latest to oldest) and pick the first bot event using the `next()` function.

The event will be have the following format:

```
{'event': 'bot', 'timestamp': 1601789469.174273, 'text': 'Hey! How are you?', 'data': {'elements': None, 'quick_replies': None, 'buttons': None, 'attachment': None, 'image': None, 'custom': None}, 'metadata': {}}
```

There you can simply take the `'text'` param if you are only interested in the message.